# Create an onscreen swipe keyboard for Mac

Tags: keyboard

Due to health issues I’m losing the use of my hands and speech. I’m looking for an onscreen keyboard for my Mac that allows swiping to type. That way I could “type” with a trackpad and stylus fairly easily and easily compared to trying to click each key onscreen or one at a time on a keyboard.  Does one exsist? How hard would it be to make? Where would I start?